# Golang worker pool not returning any results

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I was trying to build a simple TCP port scanner to practice learning concurrency in Go. I was following this youtube video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvgVSSpwND8) guide on implementing a "Worker Pool" in Go using channels and Goroutines. I tried utilising the idea from the video and I implemented TCP Scanner function as follows:

```
func worker(ports <-chan int, results chan<- string) {
    for p := range ports {
        address := fmt.Sprintf("127.0.0.1:%d", p)
        conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", address)
        if err != nil {
            results <- fmt.Sprintf("Port %d is closed: %s", p, err.Error())
        } else {
            conn.Close()
            results <- fmt.Sprintf("Port %d is open", p)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    ports := make(chan int, 100)
    results := make(chan string, 100)

    for i := 0; i < cap(ports); i++ {
        go worker(ports, results)
    }

    for j := 1; j <= 65535; j++ {
        ports <- j
    }
    close(ports)

    for k := 1; k <= 65535; k++ {
        fmt.Println(<-results)
    }
    close(results)
}
```

I expected it to slowly print out the results in a random order, just like in the youtube video. But nothing was being output on the console. I tried debugging the channels and the worker functions were receiving port numbers from the ports channel, but it seems nothing is going back to the results channel.

Comment: Why are you trying to "build a simple TCP port scanner to practice learning concurrency in Go"? TCP is a complicated protocol with a lot of edge cases. If you truly want to learn about concurrency patterns in the Go language there are an huge number of other examples that have far fewer non-Go dependencies.

Comment: I was reading a book called Blackhat Go as I am interested in working in security in the future, and it just happened to be the first project on the book! One of the things they mentioned was to try and use goroutines and channels to try and improve the effiency of the port scanner (but they didn't really explain channels/goroutines in depth). I understand now that I am trying to run before I could walk haha..., I have just started reading another book called Concurrency in Go, hopefully that will teach me more. 

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are not listening to the results when you should.

The for-loop that writes to `ports` will block after the first 100 requests, because that is the size of that channel, and all the goroutines will block waiting to write to the `results` channel, because no goroutine is reading from it.

You can fix it by listening in a separate goroutine:

```
  done:=make(chan struct{})
  go func() {
      defer close(done)
      for k := 1; k <= 65535; k++ {
        fmt.Println(<-results)
      }
      close(results)
  }()

 for j := 1; j <= 65535; j++ {
        ports <- j
    }
 close(ports)
 <-done  // Wait for the reader to finish
```

Comment: ah okay. I think my understanding of goroutines and channels are not good enough, will read up more on how they work. thank you!